# AngularJS select box options disappear when an item is selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a select box bound to a model using Angularjs.
The select box options load correctly but as soon as select any single option all options disappear from the select box. What is the reason this is occuring and how do I keep my options from disappearing?

Plunker link demonstrating the issue:
http://plnkr.co/edit/DolBIN

HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  ng-app>
  <head>
      <title>Angular Test Prjoect - Home</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="Clinic.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div ng-controller="ClinicCtrl">
          <select  ng-options="item as item.start + '-' + item.end + ':' + item.patient.name for item in appointments" ng-model="appointments">
          </select>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function ClinicCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.appointments = [
        { start: "900", end: "930", provider: "1", patient: {name:"Allen",dob:"8/12/1977"} },
        { start: "1000", end: "1045", provider: "1", patient: { name: "Allen", dob: "8/12/1971"} },
        { start: "1030", end: "1100", provider: "2", patient: { name: "David", dob: "11/22/1973"} },
        { start: "1100", end: "1145", provider: "2", patient: { name: "Francine", dob: "3/18/1987"} },
        { start: "1230", end: "1530", provider: "3", patient: { name: "George", dob: "4/5/1997"} },
        { start: "1300", end: "1500", provider: "3", patient: { name: "Kirkman", dob: "6/28/1970"} }
    ];
}
```

Comment: +1, I didn't know you could do something like this: `item.start + '-' + item.end + ':' + item.patient.name` for the select list labels.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The problem is that the `ng-model` on your select element overwrites the `$scope.appointments` array as soon as an item is selected.  Use a different scope property for your `ng-model` value.

Here's an updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/EAExby

The changes to your template would be:

```
<div ng-controller="ClinicCtrl">
  <select
    ng-options="item as item.start + '-' + item.end + ':' + item.patient.name for item in appointments"
    ng-model="selectedAppointment"
  ></select>
  {{selectedAppointment}} <!-- log out the value just to show it's working -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Noah .. I am the beginner eventually found your solution :)

Comment: Thank you! I met a similar situation and fixed it by removing the ng-model from `<input />` as you pointed out the cause.